# Left adjoint to forgetful functor from topological rings to topological abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, topological-groups, adjoint-functors, topological-rings

Does the forgetful functor from the category of topological rings to the category of topological abelian groups, $U: \mathbf{TopRing} \to \mathbf{TopAb}$, have a left adjoint and if so, what is it? A reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well the mere existence of the left adjoint is immediate by the general adjoint functor theorem.  And (at least if you don't require your topological groups/rings to be Hausdorff) it's easy to see the underlying ring of the left adjoint is just the usual free ring on the underlying abelian group (since the left adjoint has to map to the free ring equipped with the indiscrete topology).  I'm not sure there's an easy description of the topology on the left adjoint in general, though.

Comment: @martini: That does not work: it can't map into any ring in which the product of two elements of $A$ is nonzero.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thx.

Comment: @EricWofsey: thank you very much. So if $f: X \to Y$ is an arbitrary continuous homomorphism of topological abelian groups, getting a sense of what $Lf: LX \to LY$ looks like in TopRing is not straightforward.

Comment: @user46484: Well, if you ignore the topologies, it will just be the free ring construction on the underlying abelian groups (which can be described explicitly as a tensor algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$).  I'm just not sure if there is an easy explicit description of what the topology looks like.

Comment: @EricWofsey: thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you have a functor from a topological category, and that functor has a left adjoint if you forget about the topological structure, then frequently (under quite mild assumptions) you can "lift" that left adjoint to the topological case.

One nice reference is Tholen's *On Wyler Taut's Lift Theorem*, which proves an even more general version of this result. Here's the special case of interest (originally due to Wyler):

Given a commutative diagram of functors

[image: a square]

where $T$ and $T'$ are [topological](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) and $\tilde{U}$ preserves initial sources, then if $U$ has a left adjoint, $\tilde{U}$ does too!

For us, $A$ and $A'$ are the categories of topological rings and groups (respesctively). These are both topological over rings, and groups, which are our $X$ and $X'$.

Then $U$ and $\tilde{U}$ should be the forgetful functors, and it's clear that initial topologies get sent to initial topologies by $\tilde{U}$ (since it's not touching the topology at all!).

So the left adjoint to $U$ lifts to a left adjoint of $\tilde{U}$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think it's clear that initial topologies are preserved. A ring topology is an additive group topology but I think the converse is false.

Comment: @ZhenLin -- hm... that's a good point. But this theorem can definitely be used to show that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{TopGrp}$ to $\mathsf{Top}$ has a left adjoint, and it's _also_ true that an initial group topology may not agree with the initial topology ignoring the group structure... I must be missing some subtlety.